# How to achieve dynamic labelFor in UI5

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a form to edit a list.

```
<VBox items="{path: 'localModel>/items', templateshareable: false}">
  <items>
    <Label text="My label" required="true" labelFor="{localModel>id}" />
    <Input required="true" />
  </items>

</VBox>
```

How can I link the labels and the inputs together?

Since UI5 does not allow dynamic id, I can not use the localModel link in the attribute `labelFor`.

Comment: Only `ManagedObject`'s _properties_ and _aggregations_ can be bound with values from a model. `Label`'s [`labelFor` is, however, an _association_](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.Label#associations) which cannot be bound.

Comment: Specifying `labelFor` dynamically is not a typical requirement which is an indication that we might be dealing with an [_xy-problem_](https://xyproblem.info/) here. Why would you need to define `labelFor` dynamically in the first place? Does the [Accessibility Guide section _Labeling and Description_](https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/accessibilityGuide/webapp/index.html#/overview/applicationDeveloper/labeling) help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a [factory](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/284a036c8ff943238fb65bf5a2676fb7) instead of a XML template. In the factory you can dynamically generate IDs and use them for both Controls, Label and Input

Answer (score 0):

```
this.byId("myLabel").setLabelFor("input1");
```